# Google maps kml layer

Tags: google-maps, kml

my code is:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
    'http://.../per1.kml',
     {suppressInfoWindows: true});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);


 var info_percurso = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: 'hi'
 });

  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function() {

  info_percurso.open(map,ctaLayer);

  alert("dd");
});
```

this is possible?
this code doesn't work...but the operation is possible?

I need to create my own infoWindow for database queries

Answer (score 4):

make sure the kml is being served. You may need to add the kml MIME type to the server.

```
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
```